# Golang Gorm retrive one to many relation with limit

Tags: go, go-gorm

Hello I have Room and Messages tables where where room has many messages. I want to get user rooms with limit 20 rooms and each room has only 20 messages only.

```golang
type Room struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID            uint        `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Hash          string      `json:"hash" binding:"required" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Users         []User      `json:"users" gorm:"many2many:room_users"`
    Messages      []Message   `json:"messages"`
    Blocked       bool        `json:"blocked" gorm:"default:false"`
    BlockerId     uint        `json:"blocker_id" gorm:"nullable:true"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time   `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time   `json:"updated_at"`
    RoomBotData   shared.RoomBotData `json:"bot_data"`
    RoomBotDataID uint        `json:"room_bot_data_id"`
}
type Message struct {
    ID        uint      `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Text      string    `json:"text" binding:"required" gorm:"not null:true"`
    UserID    uint      `json:"user_id" gorm:"not null:true"`
    RoomID    uint      `json:"room_id" gorm:"not null:true"`
    IsRead    bool      `json:"is_read" binding:"required" gorm:"default:false"`
    Type      string    `json:"type" gorm:"default:text"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
}
```

I have tried preload function and set limit to 20 for message

```golang
db.Preload("Messages", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return db.Limit(20)
}).Find(&rooms)
```

but this only get 20 messages in total for all rooms.

I also tried to get 20 messages for each room

```golang
    err = db.DB.Model(&Room{}).
        Order("updated_at DESC").
        Limit(20).
        Preload(RoomSchema.Users).
        Where("id in ?", roomIds).
        Find(&rooms).Error

    roomMessagesChannel := make(chan map[int][]Message)

    for i, room := range rooms {
        go r.getRoomMessages(roomMessagesChannel, room.ID, i)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(rooms); i++ {
        messagesMap := <-roomMessagesChannel
        firstItemOfMap := reflect.ValueOf(messagesMap).MapKeys()[0].Int()
        rooms[int(firstItemOfMap)].Messages = messagesMap[int(firstItemOfMap)]

    }

    close(roomMessagesChannel)
```

I used channels to speed up the process but it cause memory leak and consume a lot of memory. I want to do that in a better way

Comment: So this code do what you want to achieve but you want to optimise it?

Comment: @HamzaAnis I want to get 20 rooms and each room has 20 messages. Without looping over all rooms. I think there are a way like join lateral or something like that